# simple_html_dom get an input with a partial id value

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

Im trying to get td fields from a table with the id `sid-120390923` or `sid-38737122` ignoring any other id value in the table, however the problem is that I can not get these td fields because they all have a slightly different id but with the same start ('sid').

what I want is to be able to grab all the td fields with the starting id `sid-`, would there be a way to incorporate regex?

here is an example

**html**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td id='9sd'></td>
      <td id='10sd'></td>
      <td id='sid-1239812983'></td>
      <td id='sid-1454345345'></td>
      <td id='sid-2342345234'></td>
      <td id='sid-5656433455'></td>
      <td id='sid-1231235664'></td>
      <td id='sid-8986757575'></td>
      <td id='sid-1232134551'></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**simple_html_dom**

```
$table = $con->find('table');

foreach($table->find('td#sid-1232134551') as $field){
   echo $field."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [attribute filters](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) (the 5. tab),

```
$table->find('td[id^=sid-]');
```

Comment: Thanks this is just what im looking for.